# Untar multiple files at once?

Tags: windows-7, compression, tar

I'm on Windows 7 and have a number of .tar files with the following names:

```
.tar-aa
.tar-bb
.tar-cc
...
```

The tar files contain a large backup directory which is broken up into chunks of 250MBs each. What is the simplest way of uncompressing them all into one directory? If I uncompress them individually I end up with multiple directories each with a section of a file which causes errors.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` them together with a wildcard, then pipe that into `tar`, telling it read from stdin.  For example, with the GNU tar:

```
cat something.tar-* | tar -xf -
```

Answer (score 0):

Get UnxUtils or GnuWin which both contain a tar.exe. http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
Then open a command prompt and run

```
cat .tar-aa .tar-bb .tar-cc | tar xf -
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your environment, but I'll assume you have cat if you also have tar:

```
cat largebackupdirectory.tar* | tar -xf -
```

Edit: This will cat every tar file that has been broken up and pipe the output as a file into tar -xf, which extracts the tar files.

Comment: Explain your command for those who do not just want to enter in a command unknowingly.